# Can't find application class in @INC when starting Mojolicious-generated app

Tags: perl, server, mojolicious, morbo

I generated a mojolicious app with the command `mojo generate app first-app`. It generated the app structure that should allow a running example when running the dev server with `morbo ./script/first-app`.

The file structure looks like this:
[mojo app structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3cL5.png)

My error when running `morbo ./script/first-app` in the root of the project directory is this error:

```
Can't load application from file "/home/djnorrisdev/Documents/mojo-practice/first-app/script/first-app":
    Can't find application class "first-app" in @INC. (
    /home/djnorrisdev/Documents/mojo-practice/first-app/lib
    /home/djnorrisdev/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.0/lib/site_perl/5.30.0/x86_64-linux
    /home/djnorrisdev/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.0/lib/site_perl/5.30.0
    /home/djnorrisdev/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.0/lib/5.30.0/x86_64-linux
    /home/djnorrisdev/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.0/lib/5.30.0)
Compilation failed in require at (eval 72) line 1
```

(Line breaks added for readability. An indented line is a continuation of the previous line.)

I tried using the full path for morbo (as mentioned in a 6 year old SO post), but that gives the same error as above. That command was this: `/home/djnorrisdev/perl5/perlbrew/pls/perl-5.30.0/bin/morbo ./script/first-app`

I'm guessing anyone familiar with a full mojolicious app would be familiar with the script file, but here's the contents of `script/first-app` :

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Mojo::File 'curfile';
use lib curfile->dirname->sibling('lib')->to_string;
use Mojolicious::Commands;

# Start command line interface for application
Mojolicious::Commands->start_app('first-app');
```

Considering this is a mojolicious-generated app, I would assume it should not get an @INC error and run with morbo without issue. Does anyone have insight into this?

Comment: I tried this:: `mojo generate app first-app` and got error `Your application name has to be a well formed (CamelCase) Perl module name like "MyApp"`. So I tried again with `mojo generate app TestApp` and that worked. I then did `cd  test_app` and ran `morbo script/test_app` and it worked (I got the welcome page at http://127.0.0.1:3000/ ) I am using `perl` version 5.28.1, Ubuntu 19.04, Mojolicious version 8.14

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your setup to work, `first-app.pm` would have to contain `package first-app;`, but that's not legal code because of the dash. Håkon Hægland suggests that `mojo generate app first-app` should not have worked (presumably to avoid this very problem), so it's unclear how you came to have the setup you describe.

To fix the problem, you could rerun `mojo generate app` with a more suitable name (such as `FirstApp`) and start over.

Alternatively, you should theoretically be able to fix the problem with as little as three changes:

1. Rename `lib/first-app.pm` to a more conventional name such as `lib/FirstApp.pm`.
2. Change the argument passed to `->start_app` to `'FirstApp'`.
3. Change the `package` directive in now-named `lib/FirstApp.pm` to `package FirstApp;`.

A module's path, a module's `package` directive, and the `use` statement used to load the module —the value passed to `->start_app` in this case— must all match. The three changes ensures this for the module in question.

[Note: I have no experience with Mojo.]

Comment: Thank you, naming it with PascalCase worked. I previously tried #1-3 before I posted the original post, but I was still not using best naming practices that time either. As to why it didn't error out during the generate app command, I have no clue.